# Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl

Tags: java, jmeter

**Hi, I'm trying to run my java code in IntelliJ and also trying to initialize apache JMeter, but the following error is shown... Can someone please explain what could be wrong?**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:100)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95)
    ... 22 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\transactions\PetStore\all_transactions_local_server.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
cause-message       : Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:100)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/ProxyControl
line number         : 15
version             : 3.1 r1770033
```

Comment: Try using newer jmerer version

Comment: @user7294900 the same thing happens also with 5.4.1 version

Answer (score 1):

As per [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) description:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

You need to have at least:

1. Everything from JMeter's "lib" folder
2. Everything from JMeter's "lib/ext" folder

in your [project classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), once done you will be able to run your code.

You may also find [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) and [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) example project useful/interesting